# How to mock ResizeObserver polyfill in angular, when doing unit tests with jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

**My goal** is to mock out the [resize-observer-polyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill), in an Angular application when running jest unit tests.

Currently, I get the following error:

```js
TypeError: resize_observer_polyfill_1.default is not a constructor
```

I found a [related issue here](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/issues/50), and thus tried to implement a mock next to a component. So this is **what I have tried**:

*_mocks_/resizeObserver.ts*

```js
class ResizeObserver {
    observe() {
        // do nothing
    }
    unobserve() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
window.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;
export default ResizeObserver;
```

And then in my spec file import it with:

```js
import ResizeObserver from './_mocks_/resizeObserver';
```

But that does not solve the problem.

In **code**, I use the polyfill like this:

```js
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
```

It's a really frustrating issue, so I really hope to solve the issue in some way.

Comment: I faced the same issue and end up my investigation with `if (ResizeObserver) { new ResizeObserver(...) }`

Answer (score 2):

Solved issue by adding this code to my test file, just above the de `describe('...`

```
    window.ResizeObserver =
    window.ResizeObserver ||
     jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
     disconnect: jest.fn(),
     observe: jest.fn(),
     unobserve: jest.fn(),
    }));
```

Comment: I believe this is the simplest and most efficient solution, thank you for the response.

I created a utils file in my project, which exports this code snippet, and inside the describe block on my test file, I call this function with functionName(); and works good

Answer (score 1):

From that same GitHub Issue:

```js
jest.mock('resize-observer-polyfill', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

If you wanted to call the resize handler function immediately, you can add that to the implementation:

```js
jest.mock('resize-observer-polyfill', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn().mockImplementation((cb) => {
    // call event handler immediately
    cb()
 
    return {
      observe: jest.fn(),
      unobserve: jest.fn(),
      disconnect: jest.fn(),
    }
  }),
}));
```

If you wanted to call it on demand, one way you could do it is to add some actual event handlers to the observe function.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see you're importing the mock in your unit test, but you aren't using it. You need to have something like the following on top of your unit test file:

```js
import ResizeObserver from './_mocks_/resizeObserver';

jest.mock('resize-observer-polyfill', () => { return ResizeObserver; });
```